# The integral $\int f \mu(dt)$ versus $\int f \mu(t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the theory of continuous-time branching processes there is a quantity called the Malthusian parameter $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} \mu(dt) = 1 $$

The measure $\mu$ having to do with the branching process is defined as follows. The number of children of a given individual in the branching process is a point process $\xi$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$. $\mu(t)$ is simply the *reproduction function* for the branching process, which is the expected number of children of an individual by the time that individual is of age $t$. In other words, $\mu$ is the expected number of points in $[0,t]$ of $\xi$: 
$$ \mu(t) = \mathbb{E} \xi[0,t] $$
In the course of some calculations involving $\alpha$, I was being sloppy and wrote:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} \mu(dt) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} \mu(t) dt $$
I was immediately told that I am, indeed, making a boneheaded integration mistake. Instead it was suggested that to make this equality true, I need to put
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} \mu(dt) = \int_0^{\infty} \alpha e^{-\alpha t} \mu(t) dt $$
Note the extra $\alpha$ on the right-hand side. But I just can't see where this came from.

Comment: You could write $\mu(dt)=d\mu(t)=\mu'(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Did you study Radon–Nikodym theorem?

Comment: @echzhen yes. but my actual question goes a little beyond that. sorry, I've edited to make this clearer.

Comment: This is an integration by parts formula with the functions $u(t)=e^{-\alpha t}$ and $v(t)=\mu(t)$, then $u'(t)=-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}$ and $(uv)(0)=(uv)(\infty)=0$ hence $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t}\mu(dt)=\int_0^\infty u(t)v'(t)dt=\left.u(t)v(t)\right|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty u'(t)v(t)dt=0+\int_0^\infty\alpha e^{-\alpha t}\mu(t)dt.$$

Comment: @Did: wow. that probably seemed completely obvious to you, but I never would've seen it this way. much appreciated.

Comment: @Did: after checking the details again, does this technically require us to assume that $\mu(t) < \infty$? not unreasonable I suppose.

Comment: No, only that $\mu(t)\ll e^{\alpha t}$ when $t\to\infty$, to ensure that the limit $(uv)(\infty)=0$ in my previous comment holds (note that otherwise the integral in the RHS does not converge hence this is not a real restriction).

Comment: @Did: ah, I see. So I suppose that if you *can* solve $\int \alpha e^{-\alpha t} \mu(t) dt = 1$ and such an $\alpha$ exists, then $\mu(t) \ll e^{\alpha t}$ must hold. gotcha.